# Subquery inside IN clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query working:

```
SELECT DISTINCT table1.field1, table1.field2
FROM table1
WHERE table1.field3 IN (1,2,3)
```

Result:

```
 field1 field2
 Data1  60
 Data2  61
 Data3  62
```

And the following query only gives me the first row when it should give the exact same result as the first query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT table1.field1, table1.field2
FROM table1
WHERE table1.field3 IN (SELECT table2.field1 FROM table2 WHERE table2.field2 = 100)
```

Result:

```
 field1 field2
 Data1  60
```

If I execute the `subquery (SELECT table2.field1 FROM table2 WHERE table2.field2 = 100)`, the result is "1,2,3", exactly like the first query.

What i'm I missing?

Comment: can you post some sample data?

Comment: please, copy-paste query results in your post, also table `descr`. Include field3 in select clause when you post data.

Comment: Is the subquery returning three separate rows, or a sngle string `1,2,3`?

Comment: Is the result of your sub-query a single string with the value `'1,2,3'`, or do you get three records with the values `1`, `2`, and `3`?  Because `x IN (1,2,3)` *[A list of three integers]* is fundamentally different to `x IN ('1,2,3')` *[A list of one string]*

Comment: the subquery returns a single row, a string

Comment: @Dems that might be the problem then

Comment: @Tenza That's your issue.  If you run your first query with `IN ('1,2,3')` then you'll get the same results

Comment: @Tenza in that case you'll need some kind of splitting function to turn that string into effectively back into something queryable (like a table). There isn't one built into MySQL, but a google search reveals lots of them. Example here: http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you're missing is that a string with the value `'1,2,3'` is not a list of three integers.  It's one string.

If you want `x IN (SELECT y FROM z)` to behave in the same way as `x IN (1,2,3)`, then your sub-query must return three items, with the values `1`, `2`, and `3`.

There are *Split()* functions on the web that take a string and return a record set consisting of multiple integers.  And that may *fix* your problem.

But the fact that you have a single record with a single field holding multiple values is a sign of a deeper problem.  You should never store multiple values in a relational database as a single string.  Instead store multiple records, or multiple fields.